# CRC CCITT (0xFFFF) Implementation in Python

Tags: python, crc, crc16

I need to implement calculation of crc from string of zeroes and one-s like 10000000 etc

I have found this code but its for CRC CCITT(XModem)
    POLYNOMIAL = 0x1021
    PRESET = 0

```
    def _initial(c):
        crc = 0
        c = c << 8
        for j in range(8):
            if (crc ^ c) & 0x8000:
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL
            else:
                crc = crc << 1
            c = c << 1
        return crc

    _tab = [ _initial(i) for i in range(256) ]

    def _update_crc(crc, c):
        cc = 0xff & c

        tmp = (crc >> 8) ^ cc
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ _tab[tmp & 0xff]
        crc = crc & 0xffff

        return crc

    def crc(str):
        crc = PRESET
        for c in str:
            crc = _update_crc(crc, ord(c))
        return crc

    def crcb(*i):
        crc = PRESET
        for c in i:
            crc = _update_crc(crc, c)
        print crc
        return crc
```

Changing PRESET to 0xFFFF as it is initial value for CRC CCITT (0xFFFF) doesnt help.

Does anyone can help to rewrite or adapt this code? For reaching a result? For checking uses https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

Downloading and installation crc16 library not allowed due security reasons

Python2.7

Comment: As it stands above for control uses lammertbies website. As long results are different it means something wrong.

Comment: What is your input and what is your expected output? Show a _complete_ example in Python.